# Permutation/cyclic type question

Tags: group-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Problem from Armstrong's book, “Groups and Symmetry”](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/63638/problem-from-armstrongs-book-groups-and-symmetry)

If $a$, $b$ are members of the permutation group $S_n$, and $ab=ba$.  Show that $b$ must be a power of $a$ when $a$ is an $n$-cycle.

Answer (score 1):

Recall the following facts.

(1) Two elements of $S_n$ are conjugate if and only if they have the same cycle structure. Hence, the orbit of $a$ under the action of conjugation by elements of $S_n$ is exactly the $n$-cycles.

(2) There are (n-1)! $n$-cycles in $S_n$

(3) The size of the orbit of $a$ under the action of conjugation in $S_n$ times the size of the centralizer of $a$ is equal to the order of $S_n.$

It follows there are exactly $n$ elements that commute with $a.$ As every power of $a$ is such an element, we conclude the $C_{S_n}(a) = \langle a \rangle.$

Comment: Would you mind terribly moving this answer to the other question (I link to it in the comment above)? That one includes a bit more and already has some answers. This is an exact duplicate (down to the wording) of the second half of that answer.

Comment: Will do. Give me nine key strokes.

Comment: If the downvote has to do with the logistics of the repeated question, I would ask the downvoter to remove it. If there is some other reason, kindly explain it.

Comment: Downvote?? ${}$

Comment: I know. I hope it's not because of my comment...